# Which method do I execute with different parameter?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class Superhero {
    String s;
    public Superhero() {
        s = "I'M A SUPERHERO";
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public void punch() {
        System.out.println("Punch! Punch!");
    }

    public void punch(Superhero a) {
        System.out.println("BOOM" + s);
    }
}
public class Batman extends Superhero {
    String s;
    public Batman() {
       s = "NANANANANA";
    }

    public Batman(String s) {
           this.s = s;
       System.out.println(this.s);
    }

    public void punch(Superhero v) {
        s = "BATMAN!";
        super.punch(v);
        System.out.println("BOOM " + s);
    }

    public void punch(Batman b) {
        System.out.println("Wat.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Superhero superhero = new Batman();
        superhero.punch( (Batman) superhero);
    }
}
```

In main, why would this be a valid code? wouldn't it look for `punch(Batman b)` function on the static type which is `Superhero` and since there's no function that matches the signature exactly, wouldn't this be a compile-time error? According to what it does, it executes `punch(Superhero a)` on Superhero class.

This results in

```
"I'M A SUPERHERO"
"BOOM I'M A SUPERHERO"
"BOOM BATMAN!
```

Comment: Caution! Your variable `s` in `Batman` shadows `s` in `Superhero`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Batman** is a **Superhero** so `public void punch(Superhero a)` is perfectly valid to be called with a **Batman** parameter.

To clarify, `public void punch(Superhero a)` states that the punch method may be called with any type of Superhero object.  Since all classes which are subtypes of Superhero are Superheros themselves this method can take any Superhero or any subtype of Superhero as a parameter.

Comment: ironic that a superhero question is answered by the Joker :)